# android adb modify build.prop file

Tags: android, adb, push

i have a device Zebra TC75X under android 6.0 connected on usb in my window computer cable, developer option is set, and debug mode is on.
I would like to modify the build.prop locate in folder /system add a property and replace the file.

For to do that, i have used adb but actually nothing works !
i do this :

```
adb devices
adb pull /system/build.prop
```

file build.prop are copy to folder : plateform-tools
i edit the file with notepad++ save it

and finally i used this command:

```
adb push build.prop /system/
```

but i receive this message:
adb:error failed to copy build.prop to system/build.prop remote read only file system

How i can REPLACE this file ?
thanks for your time and your explanation

Comment: If your device is rooted run following adb command before push: `adb root`, `adb remount`.

Comment: Hello xinlake, my device isn't root ...we don't want to root the device i think it will be possible  to do this WITHOUT root the device ! It's the same things than modify some settings in a .ini file on window system ...I'm new to android

Comment: _It will be an impossible mission ^^._ Android based on linux, System partition is mounted in read-only mode, The partition needs to be mounted as read-write mode with root to write file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mount system partition to do that. Search for unlocking bootloader and installing custom recovery like twrp for your device.

Comment: Hello c.soylu ok but i've just to check on internet TWRP and i think the app TWRP ROOT the device ? is it true ? And of course we don't want to root the device ...

Comment: Directly, no. You can root the device via twrp but installing twrp doesn't mean rooting. It has root privileges to mount system partition which is not available on stock recovery.

Comment: Hello c soylu, thanks for your time a support has been open to the panasonic society . My goal is to disable multi user on this tablet. Have a nice year for all